# sql left join with condition

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I have this problem with SQLite in Android:

From **items** I should get:

1) all items with title field containing a string . example '%sho%'

2) check if item belongs to a given project (22)

```
project
┌───┬─────────┐
│ id│idProject│
├───┼─────────┤
│ 1 │      1  │
│ 2 │      22 │
└───┴─────────┘
items         projectitems
┌───┬──────┐  ┌───┬─────────┬─────────┐
│id │ title│  │ id│  idItem │idProject│
├───┼──────┤  ├───┼─────────┼─────────┤
│10 │ show1│  │ 1 │      10 │      22 │
│11 │ show2│  │ 2 │      11 │      22 │
│12 │ show3│  │ 3 │      12 │      22 │
│13 │ show4│  │ 4 │      10 │       1 │
│14 │ show5│  │ 5 │      11 │       1 │
│15 │ show6│  │ 6 │      12 │       1 │
└───┴──────┘  └───┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
  e.id, e.title, l.idProject 
from 
  items as e 
LEFT JOIN projectitems as l
  on e.id = l.idItem
WHERE 
  e.title LIKE '%sho%' AND l.idProject = 22
ORDER BY 
  e.title ASC
```

the result I'm getting is:

```
id  title   idProject
10  show1   22
11  show2   22
12  show3   22
```

the result I want:

```
id  title   idProject
10  show1   22
11  show2   22
12  show3   22
13  show4   (null)
14  show5   (null)
15  show6   (null)
```

Also if you know different approaches to accomplish this, let me know.
thanks.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0008f/7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the criterion from the `WHERE` clause to `ON`:

```
SELECT 
  e.id, e.title, l.idProject 
from 
  items as e 
LEFT JOIN projectitems as l
  on e.id = l.idItem
  and l.idProject = 22
WHERE
   e.title LIKE '%sho%'
ORDER BY 
  e.title ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move `l.idProject = 22` to `ON` clause:

```
SELECT 
  e.id, e.title, l.idProject 
from 
  items as e 
LEFT JOIN projectitems as l
  on e.id = l.idItem AND l.idProject = 22
WHERE 
  e.title LIKE '%sho%' 
ORDER BY 
  e.title ASC
```

Placing the predicate in the `WHERE` clause turns `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.